# LaunchUriAsync with Authentication and other custom headers

Tags: authentication, windows-phone-8.1, single-sign-on

I am new to windows phone development. I have an app and a website and both of them needs authentication. When I launch the website from my app and if the user is already authenticated I want to pass the authentication headers so the user doesn't need to authenticate again on the website.
I am using `LaunchUriAsync` to launch the `URI` but the method is not taking any headers, how can I pass headers to my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do this. You have to use a WebView embedded into your app.